# Querying database values from a column in Grails with Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, grails, groovy, hql

Im new to grails and I try to get a database entry.
The database connection works without problems.

In the database Ive got a class named "Correct" which contains correct answers (booleans), so its structure is:

> id | version | answera | ... | answerh | lpicid

lpicid references to a question. for each lpicid there is only ONE entry. primary key is id.

Now when I want to call the correct answers and save the answers in variables, this doesnt really work:

```
    def correctanswers = Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=" + lpicid);

    def correcta = correctanswers.answera();
```

I get an database entry, I can see that (lpicid is just a def number), but correctanswers.answera() does not work. I always get this message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.answera() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: inspect(), clear(), clear(), clear(), any(), asList()
    at com.lpic.LpicSimulatorController$_closure2.doCall(LpicSimulatorController.groovy:76)
    at com.lpic.LpicSimulatorController$_closure2.doCall(LpicSimulatorController.groovy)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How can I solve this in order to get the answera, answerb.... values?

thank you :-)

Comment: String concatenation like you're using is very dangerous and can allow SQL injection attacks. Although `get()` is the correct answer, in general `Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=" + lpicid)` should be `Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=?" , [lpicid])` or `Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=:id", [id: lpicid])`. See the docs at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use id directly then the easiest and most efficient ways is to call `Correct.get(id)`.

Otherwise look into the [`findBy`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html) dynamic domain method.

Answer (score 2):

instead of:

```
def correctanswers = Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=" + lpicid);
```

Can't you do:

```
def correctanswers = Correct.findByLpicid( lpicid )
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your domain class structure but i would think by removing the '()' from the end of correctanswers.answera(); that it should work because it's not a method.  I'm assuming that a 'correctanswers' as a single 'ansera' domain class.

```
def correctanswers = Correct.executeQuery("from Correct answers where answers.lpicid=" + lpicid);

def correcta = correctanswers.answera;
```